# ID3 Decision Tree in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I've been working my way through [Pedro Domingos' machine learning course](https://www.coursera.org/course/machlearning) videos (although the course is not currently active). His first homework assignment starts with coding up a decision tree (ID3). The decision tree is used in subsequent assignments (where bagging and boosting methods are to be applied over it).

My concern is that my base decision tree implementation is running at a little over 60% accuracy which seems very low to me. The hypothesis test based pruning doesn't seem to be making much of a difference either. Given that most of the subsequent assignments rely on this code, it's frustrating not to be sure it's working properly.

I've written and re-written this class many times now and can't figure out where I'm going wrong (if I am). The parts of the code that most concern me are my information gain calculations and the chi-square based hypothesis test but it's very possible I missed something obvious somewhere else.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st


def entropy(attribute_data):
    """
    Calculate Shannon entropy
    :param attribute_data: data from a single feature/attribute
    :return: a float representing the Shannon entropy
    """
    _, val_freqs = np.unique(attribute_data, return_counts=True)
    # probabilities for each unique attribute value
    val_probs = val_freqs / len(attribute_data)
    return -val_probs.dot(np.log(val_probs))


def info_gain(attribute_data, labels):
    """
    Calculate information gain
    :param attribute_data: data from single attribute
    :param labels:
    :return: a float representing information gain
    """
    attr_val_counts = get_count_dict(attribute_data)
    total_count = len(labels)
    EA = 0.0
    for attr_val, attr_val_count in attr_val_counts.items():
        EA += attr_val_count * entropy(labels[attribute_data == attr_val])

    return entropy(attribute_data) - EA / total_count


def get_count_dict(data):
    """
    Return the unique values and their frequencies as a dictionary
    :param data: a 1-D numpy array
    :return:
    """
    data_values, data_freqs = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
    return dict(zip(data_values, data_freqs))


def hypothesis_test(attribute_data, labels, p_threshold=None, return_p_value=False):
    """
    Perform a chi-square test on the values for an attribute and their corresponding labels
    :param attribute_data:
    :param labels:
    :param p_threshold:
    :param return_p_value:
    :return: True/False for p value exceeding threshold and optionally the p value tested
    """
    # Get label frequencies
    label_counts = get_count_dict(labels)
    # Get attribute value frequencies
    attr_val_counts = get_count_dict(attribute_data)
    # Calculate length of data (outside of loops below)
    total_count = len(labels)

    # k and m will be used for degrees of freedom in chi-squared call
    # k unique classes
    k = len(label_counts)
    # m unique attribute values
    m = len(attr_val_counts)

    statistic = 0.0
    for attr_val, attr_val_count in attr_val_counts.items():
        attr_val_ratio = attr_val_count / total_count
        # Get corresponding label frequencies within this attribute value
        label_counts_attr_val = get_count_dict(labels[attribute_data == attr_val])
        for label_attr_val, label_count_attr_val in label_counts_attr_val.items():
            # Expected label count is the probability of the attribute value by the
            # probability of the label within the attribute
            exp_label_count_attr_val = attr_val_ratio * label_counts[label_attr_val]
            # Calculate the Chi-square statistic
            statistic += (label_count_attr_val - exp_label_count_attr_val)**2 / exp_label_count_attr_val

    # Calculate the p value from the chi-square distribution CDF
    p_value = 1 - st.chi2.cdf(statistic, df=(m-1)*(k-1))

    if return_p_value:
        return p_value < p_threshold, p_value
    else:
        return p_value < p_threshold


# Main decision tree class. There'll be one instance of the class per node.
class DecisionTree:
    # Main prediction at this node
    label = None
    # Split attribute for the children
    attribute = None
    # Attribute value (where attribute has been set by parent)
    attribute_value = None
    # A list of child nodes (DecisionTree)
    children = None
    # p value for hypothesis testing
    p_value = None
    # Threshold to test p value against
    p_threshold = None
    # the parent node (DecisionTree)
    parent = None
    # level down the tree. 1 is top level
    level = None
    # max depth, for pruning
    max_level = 10000000

    def __init__(self, data, labels, attributes, fitness_func=info_gain, value=None, parent=None, p_threshold=1.0, max_level=None, old_level=0):
        """
        Create a Decision tree node
        :param data: Attribute values (example inputs)
        :param labels: example outputs
        :param attributes: Attribute column references
        :param fitness_func: A function to test goodness of fit
        :param value: Value of the parent's split attribute
        :param parent:
        :param p_threshold: threshold for hypothesis test
        :param max_level: maximum tree depth
        :param old_level: parent's level in the tree
        :return:
        """
        self.level = old_level + 1
        self.p_threshold = p_threshold

        if max_level is not None:
            self.max_level = max_level

        if value is not None:
            self.attribute_value = value

        if parent is not None:
            self.parent = parent

        # If data or remaining attributes are empty or we've reached max depth then set the node label to the most
        # common one and return
        if data.size == 0 or not attributes or self.level == self.max_level:
            try:
                # self.label = st.mode(labels)[0][0][0]
                self.label = st.mode(labels)[0][0]
            except:
                self.label = labels[len(labels) - 1]
            return

        # If labels are all the same, set label and return
        if np.all(labels[:] == labels[0]):
            self.label = labels[0]
            return

        # If corresponding attribute values are the same on every example just pick the last label and return
        # Implemented as a loop so we can stop checking as soon as we find a mismatch
        examples_all_same = True
        for i in range(1, data.shape[0]):
            for j in range(data.shape[1]):
                if data[0, j] != data[i, j]:
                    examples_all_same = False
                    break
            if not examples_all_same:
                break
        if examples_all_same:
            # Choose the last label
            self.label = labels[len(labels) - 1]
            return

        # Build the tree by splitting the data and adding child trees
        self.build(data, labels, attributes, fitness_func)
        return

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.children is None:
            return "x[{0}]={1}, y={2}".format(self.parent.attribute, self.attribute_value, self.label)
        else:
            if self.parent is not None:
                return "x[{0}]={1}, p={2}".format(self.parent.attribute, self.attribute_value, self.p_value)
            else:
                return "p={0}".format(self.p_value)

    def build(self, data, labels, attributes, fitness_func):
        """
        build a subtree
        :param data:
        :param labels:
        :param attributes:
        :param fitness_func:
        :return:
        """
        self.choose_best_attribute(data, labels, attributes, fitness_func)
        best_attribute_column = attributes.index(self.attribute)
        # Attribute data is the single column with attribute values for the best attribute
        attribute_data = data[:, best_attribute_column]

        # Prune if hypothesis test fails
        no_prune, self.p_value = hypothesis_test(attribute_data, labels, return_p_value=True, p_threshold=self.p_threshold)

        if not no_prune:
            # The try-return is probably not required here and above
            try:
                self.label = st.mode(labels)[0][0]
            except:
                self.label = labels[len(labels) - 1]
            return

        # The child trees will be passed data for all attributes except the split attribute
        child_attributes = attributes[:]
        child_attributes.remove(self.attribute)

        self.children = []
        for val in np.unique(attribute_data):
            # Create children for data where the split attribute == val for each unique value for the attribute
            child_data = np.delete(data[attribute_data == val,:], best_attribute_column,1)
            child_labels = labels[attribute_data == val]
            self.children.append(DecisionTree(child_data, child_labels, child_attributes, value=val, parent=self,
                                              old_level=self.level, max_level=self.max_level))

    def choose_best_attribute(self, data, labels, attributes, fitness):
        """
        Choose an attribute to split the children on
        :param data: values for all attributes
        :param labels: values for corresponding labels
        :param attributes: attribute columns
        :param fitness: the closeness of fit function
        :return: empty ... self.attribute will be set by this function instead
        """
        best_gain = float('-inf')
        for attribute in attributes:
            attribute_data = data[:, attributes.index(attribute)]
            gain = fitness(attribute_data, labels)
            if gain > best_gain:
                best_gain = gain
                self.attribute = attribute
        return

    def classify(self, data):
        """
        Make predictions for the rows passed in data
        :param data: rows of attribute values
        :return: a numpy array of labels
        """
        if data.size == 0:
            return

        # If we're down to one record then convert it back to a 2-D array
        if len(data.shape) == 1:
            data = np.reshape(data, (1,len(data)))

        if self.children is None:
            # If we're at the bottom of the tree then return the labels for all records as the tree node label
            labels = np.ones(len(data)) * self.label
            return labels

        labels = np.zeros(len(data))

        for child in self.children:
            # Get the array indexes where the split attibute value  = child attribute value
            child_attr_val_idx = data[:,self.attribute] == child.attribute_value
            # pass the array subsets to child trees for classification
            labels[child_attr_val_idx] = child.classify(data[child_attr_val_idx])

        return labels
```

My full code (with bagging) with along with the data is on GitHub at https://github.com/jabbermonkey/dtree_bias_var

I'd love to know if I've missed something in this implementation. Any general comments on the code are also very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that my Information Gain calculation was incorrect. I was subtracting from the entropy of the filtered attribute-specific data and I should have been subtracting from the entropy all the data. This can be achieved by calculating entropy on the labels rather than the data.

So:

```
return entropy(attribute_data) - EA / total_count
```

should be

```
return entropy(labels) - EA / total_count
```

Thanks to user [surajrautela](https://github.com/surajrautela) on Github for raising an issue to point this out.